# Can Passkeys act as FIDO2 U2F devices, replacing YubiKeys?

Tags: authentication, two-factor-authentication, passkey

To put it more precisely, can Apple's new Passkeys feature allow Apple devices to basically use their built-in Secure Enclaves like built-in U2F devices, replacing external USB security dongles like YubiKeys? So your two factor authentication (2FA) factors become "something you have" (an Apple device with your Passkey private keys in the Secure Enclave), and "something you are" (your face/fingerprint biometrics)?

I seem to recall that the new Passkeys feature that Apple announced at WWDC 2022 to be in Apple's Fall 2022 OS updates (iOS 16, macOS 13 Ventura, Safari 16, etc.) seems to be built, at least in part, on industry standard authentication schemes such as FIDO2.

I know FIDO2 is what allows "Universal Second Factor" (U2F) devices like YubiKey USB dongles to work as a physical multifactor authentication (MFA) devices.

Putting those two things together, does that mean that the Passkeys feature will allow me to use my Apple devices (via FaceID/TouchID and Secure Enclave) as FIDO2 U2F devices, obviating the need for dedicated U2F USB dongles such as YubiKeys?

For a concrete example, when signing into Amazon Web Services (AWS), one option for MFA is to use FIDO2 to support things like YubiKeys; this keeps you from needing to hassle with getting a 6-digit TOTP code from an Authenticator apps, or using insecure SMS to get a code sent to you. I'm hoping I'll be able to select that MFA method on AWS but set it up to use Passkeys instead of needing a YubiKey.

Comment: Effectively, yes - however they do not emulate those keys and websites need to allow them.

Comment: @Ezekiel I think what I'm really trying to get at is, do websites that already support FIDO2 (and already trigger that special browser UI) need to do anything additional to support Passkeys?

Comment: Depending on how they implemented, yes they do. For example, if you try to add a passkey on some sites, you'll only see a prompt to insert a security key. The passkey option won't show up.

Comment: For others, it'll automatically work since they (probably) request a more broad type of security process.

Comment: Well, I was finally able to test it, and the AWS MFA flow for FIDO U2F devices like YubiKeys did not trigger the Passkeys UI on Safari 16 on macOS 12.6 Monterey (I don't have macOS 13 Ventura handy to test with); it only triggered the same U2F UI that Safari 15 already contained. However, the Passkeys demo at https://passkeys.io/ did trigger the Passkeys UI on the same Safari/macOS combo. One more data point: My passkey generated for the demo site did NOT seem to get sync'd via iCloud my iPhone running iOS 16; the UI on my iPhone wanted me to use some kind of QRcode-based flow.